# Sequelize - Retrieve association after model creation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating a model through a relation, I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the relation in the return of the model.

Company Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const company = sequelize.define('company', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })

    company.hasMany(sequelize.models.flow, {foreignKey: 'company_id', as: 'flows'})
}
```

Flow model

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const flow = sequelize.define('flow', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        company_id: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        }
    })

    flow.belongsTo(sequelize.models.company, {foreignKey: 'company_id', as: 'company'})
}
```

Query

```
const company = await ORM.models.company
    .findOne({
        where: {
            uuid: req.body.company_id
        }
    })

if (company) {
    const flow = await company.createFlow({
        name: req.body.name
    })

    return res.json(flow)
}
```

I am currently getting the following response:

```
{
    "uuid": "647aa7b2-163a-4bab-80f6-441c9bf29915",
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Flow 2",
    "company_id": 2,
    "updated_at": "2021-02-11T06:08:25.160Z",
    "created_at": "2021-02-11T06:08:25.160Z",
    "description": null
}
```

I would like to obtain:

```
{
   "uuid":"647aa7b2-163a-4bab-80f6-441c9bf29915",
   "id":12,
   "name":"Flow 2",
   "updated_at":"2021-02-11T06:08:25.160Z",
   "created_at":"2021-02-11T06:08:25.160Z",
   "description":null,
   "company":{
      "id":2,
      "uuid":"3dea2541-a505-4f0c-a356-f1a2d449d050",
      "name":"Company 1",
      "created_at":"2021-02-11T05:48:11.872Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-02-11T05:48:11.872Z"
   }
}
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not attaching company data with the result JSON data structure, so you are getting only flow data.
To get the expected result please try to modify the JSON structure as follows:

```
flow.company = company;
```

just before the `return res.json(flow)`.

Comment: This method did not work, still receiving just the flow object